# Null pointer exception in SessionFactoryImpl#getReturnTypes on delete

Tags: java, database, hibernate, nullpointerexception

This line throws a NPE rooted in `SessionFactoryImpl#getReturnTypes` method:

```
    Query q = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Table t WHERE row = :row"), Table.class);
```

To be more specific the method returning the null value is `HQLQueryPlan#getReturnMetadata()`, that's why this instruction in `SessionFactoryImpl#getReturnTypes` fails:

```
return queryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan( queryString, false, CollectionHelper.EMPTY_MAP ).getReturnMetadata().getReturnTypes();
```

For some reason the selects on that table are working fine, and I recall seeing a delete work as well on the same table, but I don't know where something might have been lost or changed. The last thing I remember doing was removing all rows from the table, but I don't think that has anything to do with the issue.

Any idea what might be wrong?

This one did work:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM Table t WHERE row = ?");
```

But I still don't know why the other one does not, and as I said, the selects do work fine.

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getReturnTypes(SessionFactoryImpl.java:812)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.getReturnTypes(AbstractQueryImpl.java:193)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:278)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
at $Proxy87.createQuery(Unknown Source)
at com.xyz.persistence.dao.myDAO.deleteStuff(myDao.java:652)
```

Comment: How do you initialize "em",May be session is not available for another transaction, is your "em" value null ?

Comment: Stack trace added and em is not null. Selects do work fine

Answer (score 4):

because your DELETE query won't return a 'type' the query won't accept the resultClass parameter, Table.class

its a kooky api

Answer (score 0):

Check your domain object `Table`. Hibernate is not being able to recover metadata for that object, so may be the problem is there. If you're using JPA check your `persistence.xml` file and ensure your domain object is included.

Comment: The class is listed in the persistence.xml and the annotations seem right, otherwise I suppose selects wouldn't work, but they do work.

Comment: Your error looks like the error Hibernate throws when there are problems with your domain objects. With Hibernate 3.6.2 same stack trace. It's only a clue, because your selects do work.